Adding image to listview in Delphi not showing
I have a listview in a Multi-device form using Delphi 12.
I'm trying to add a image, but the image is not showing just a blank space.
I don't know if it's the way I download the Image or do I have to convert it?
I spend the whole day trying everything, look at all examples, but all of them had the images in a table or in a imagelist. I know I'm loading the Image twice since I want to check for nil.
Here is the code:
var
jsa: TJSONArray;
jso : TJsonObject;
i: Integer;
Name: String;
LItem: TListViewItem;
begin

if Length(S) > 10 then
   begin
      jso := TJSonObject.ParseJSONValue(S) as TJsonObject;
      if jso <> nil then
         Try
            jsa := jso.GetValue('results') as TJSONArray;
            if Jsa.Count > 0 then
               begin
                  for I := 0 to jsa.Count-1 do
                     begin                             
                         LItem := ListView1.Items.Add;
                         if GetImageFromURL(jsa[i].GetValue<string>('image')) <> nil then
                            LItem.Bitmap := GetImageFromURL(jsa[i].GetValue<string>('image'));
                         LItem.Detail := jsa[i].GetValue<string>('text');
                         LItem.Text := jsa[i].GetValue<string>('expire');
                     end;
               end;
        Finally
             jso.Free;
        End;

   end;

Here is the function that gets the image from a webserver.
function TPromoForm.GetImageFromURL(const S: String): TBitmap;
var
   ms       : TMemoryStream;
   httpCli  : TNetHTTPClient;
   resp     : IHTTPResponse;
   url      : String;
   Image: TBitmap;
begin
result := nil;
httpCli := TNetHTTPClient.Create(nil);
try
    httpCli.UserAgent := 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64; rv:44.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/44.0';
    ms := TMemoryStream.Create();
    Image  := TBitmap.Create;
    Image := nil;
    try
        url  := S;
        resp := httpCli.Get(url, ms);
        if resp.StatusCode <> 200 then
           Showmessage(Format('HTTP Error=%d %s', [resp.StatusCode, resp.StatusText]))
        else
          begin
            try
              Image  := TBitmap.Create;
              ms.Position := 0;
              Image.LoadFromStream(ms);
              result := Image;
            finally
              Image.Free;
            end;
          end;
    finally
        ms.Free;
    end;
finally
    httpCli.Free;
end;
end;

The image is a jpg.
Thanks for any help.
Kim

"I know I'm loading the Image twice since I want to check for nil"- you don't need to (nor should you) download it twice. Download it once, save it to a variable, and check if the variable is nil before using it. However, in this example, checking for nil is redundant and can be skipped, as it is safe to assign nil to the TListViewItem.Bitmap

You could at least have tried to assign a local picture instead of implying it's "not showing" in a "listview in Delphi" so you could have ruled out the HTTP part is your actual problem. A "Programmer since 1980" should know better.

Sorry, I did and it is showing.

You are Free'ing the TBitmap object before you exit from GetImageFromURL(), thus you are assigning an invalid object to the TListViewItem.Bitmap.
You need to either:

Get rid of Image.Free inside of GetImageFromURL() and let it return the object to the caller, who will then have to Free it after using it.

Have the caller pass in a valid TBitmap object, such as the TListViewItem.Bitmap, for GetImageFromURL() to fill in.



Thanks Remy, I had the feeling that Result would be erased with the Free. The reason I thought it would work is because in the Delphi samples under Listview / VariableHeightItems sample, it shows a procedure with the TBitmap result even the result is not used in the sample. I have this app which I wrote in Android Studio and no rewriting in Delphi, because I need a iPhone version as well. I Android (Java) you are able to make a object and design the layout with labels, Image, etc.. then that object would be the listview item, I was looking around for an example, but was not able to find any.

@KimHJ Are you talking here about GetDimensionBitmap function from the mentioned example? If so notice that they are two Bitmap objects being created in that function. First Bitmap is created and assigned to result at line 84. This one is never freed from within the function. The second Bitmap is then created and assigned to TextBitmap variable. at line 102 This bitmap is used for rendering text into it and is later rotated by 90 degrees (line 113) and drawn on to bitmap that was assigned to result (line 114). ...

... Later on (line 117) this TextBitmap is being freed as it is no longer needed since its content has been drawn on to result bitmap. But as I said before result bitmap is never freed within the scope of this function as it needs to exist longer so it can be used by other code outside the scope of this function.

Thanks, I didn't noticed that part.
